# Using BI LSTM CTC Tensorflow Model in Android

Tags: android, deep-learning, lstm, handwriting-recognition

TL;DR, I want to know how to use a bi-lstm-ctc tensorflow model in an android application.

I have succeeded in training my bi-lstm-ctc tensorflow model and now I want to use it for my handwriting recognition android application. Here's the part of the code that defines the graph I used:

```
self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, network_config.num_features], name="input")
self.labels = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32, name="label")
self.seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="seq_len_input")

logits = self._bidirectional_lstm_layers(
   network_config.num_hidden_units,
   network_config.num_layers,
   network_config.num_classes
)

self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
self.loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=self.labels, inputs=logits, sequence_length=self.seq_len)
self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(self.loss)

self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(network_config.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost)
self.decoded, self.log_prob = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=logits, sequence_length=self.seq_len, merge_repeated=False)
self.dense_decoded = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(self.decoded[0], default_value=-1, name="output")
```

I also succeeded in freezing and optimizing the graph following the freeze and optimize graph codes in this [tutorial](https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html). Here's the part of the code that is supposed to run the model:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, 128, true);
int[] intValues = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
float[] floatValues = new float[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    final int val = intValues[i];
    floatValues[i] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF));
}
float[] result = new float[80];
long[] INPUT_SIZE = new long[]{1, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth()};
inferenceInterface.feed(config.getInputName(), floatValues, INPUT_SIZE);
inferenceInterface.feed("seq_len_input", new int[]{bitmap.getWidth()}, 1);
inferenceInterface.run(config.getOutputNames());
inferenceInterface.fetch(config.getOutputNames()[0], result);

return result.toString();
```

However, I encounter these problems depending on the model I use. If I use the frozen graph, I encounter this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support
Op 'SparseToDense' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT64]
device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; Tindices in [DT_INT32]

[[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT64, Tindices=DT_INT64, validate_indices=true](CTCBeamSearchDecoder, CTCBeamSearchDecoder:2, CTCBeamSearchDecoder:1, output/default_value)]]
```

If I use the optimized frozen graph, I encounter this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: NodeDef expected inputs '' do not match 1 inputs 
specified; Op<name=Const; signature= -> output:dtype; attr=value:tensor; attr=dtype:type>; 
NodeDef: stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/add/y = Const[dtype=DT_INT32, 
value=Tensor<type: int32 shape: [] values: 1>](stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/Switch:1)
```

Aside from the way to address these errors, I have other questions/clarifications:

How do I address these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already made it work. The solution can also be found in this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13651).

Apparently, the issue was the types used. I was passing int64 where only int32 is accepted.

```
self.dense_decoded = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(self.decoded[0], default_value=-1, name="output")
```

To address that issue, I casted the sparse tensor elements to int32:

```
self.dense_decoded = tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.to_int32(self.decoded[0].indices),
               tf.to_int32(self.decoded[0].dense_shape),
               tf.to_int32(self.decoded[0].values),
               name="output")
```

Running the application after that gave me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,1056], In[1]: [160,128]
[[Node:stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/bw/basic_lstm_cell/basic_lstm_cell/

MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]

(stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/bw/basic_lstm_cell/basic_lstm_cell/concat, 
stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/while/bw/basic_lstm_cell/basic_lstm_cell/MatMul/Enter)]]
```

For some weird reason, changing the image width from 1024 to 128 in the java code fixed that error. Running the app again gave me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot use java.nio.FloatArrayBuffer with Tensor of type INT32
```

The problem arised upon fetching the output. With that, I knew the model ran successfully but the application just couldn't fetch results.

```
inferenceInterface.run(outputs);
inferenceInterface.fetch(outputs[0], result); //where the error happens
```

Silly ol' me forgot that outputs is an integer array, not a float array. So, I changed the type of the result array to an int array:

```
//float[] result = new float[80];
int[] result = new int[80];
```

Thus making the application work. The accuracy of the model is not good since it wasn't trained properly. I was just trying to get it to work in the application. It's time for some serious training!